# HTML Dropdown set dictionary value as selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a HTML drop down. The data source for the drop down is a dictionary. The selected values key will be stored in a hidden field. On page reload i want to set the value in the dictionary as a selected value of drop down. The dictionary key will be stored in hidden field.

```
var IxCustomer = $(_this.IxCustomerHiddenFieldId).val();

$(_this.CustomerSelectId).find("option[value=" + IxCustomer  + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

How can i modify this.

Comment: Can you please put your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(_this.CustomerSelectId).val(IxCustomer);
```

Setting the value of a `<select>` element makes the corresponding option be selected.